# Problem with cloning array through [...] or slice(0)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Could someone explain what happened with array when i clone it throw [...] or .spit(0)

I was trying it on the console, i think its enough.

```js
const a = [{cid: 1, c: []}];
const b = [...a];
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  b[i].f = 1;                 
}
```

I cloned 'a' to 'b' and made loop by 'b' and modify 'b' but changed 'a' and 'b'? HOW COME?

But if i use .pop or .shift by 'b' changed just 'b'

Comment: Those only create a *shallow* copy. The array is different, the objects contained inside are the same.

Comment: I know it. But why .pop or .shift work? And how i can clone and receive a new array without link to old array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only creates a shallow copy, so you only copied the reference to the object. You should create a deep copy, which copies everything inside the object too. You can do this using lodash (https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) like this:

```
var _ = require("lodash");
...
const a = [{cid: 1, c: []}];
const b = _.cloneDeep(a);
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  b[i].f = 1;                 
}
```

Comment: Thank you i know i tried this way) But i think spread operator create full copy into array

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**: that happens because inside your array you have an object.
And you did not make a copy of the object. Instead, you copied a reference to the object.

**Solutions**:

- If you want to **copy an array of objects with one level nesting**, you can do something like this:

  `const arr2 = arr1.map(obj => ({...obj}));`
- But if you want to **copy an array of complex objects** with several nested levels or arrays with another objects, etc, you will need to do a **deep copy of each object**. In order to do that you can use something like [lodash method _.cloneDeep(value)](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep) or another tool.

Comment: You mean i should use recursion for clone object?

Comment: Yes, I just edited the answer to clarify it. In order to do a deep copy of an object you can use something like `lodash method _.cloneDeep(value)` or another tool or make a custom function with recursion.